# Type mismatch: 'Server.HTMLEncode' ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I need to encode the content of a record and i'm using this code:

```
If(rsScadenze("testo") <> "") Then
    myString = rsScadenze("testo") 'this is a result of a query
    myEncodeString=Server.HTMLEncode(myString) 'here there is my error
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Is the result in your record NULL?

Try Server.HTMLEncode(rsScadenze("testo") & "")

Comment: Now it works. The result in my record is NULL, you're right. But in my database there is something, why the result is NULL?

Comment: You have to post more of your code for anyone to be able to answer that.

Comment: I execute the same code out of the IF and it runs. Why if i run the code into IF condition it doesn't work?

Comment: try If isNull(rsScadenze("testo")) == false

Comment: i try but i have a syntax error. So i have tried: If isNull(rsScadenze("testo"))= false. It runs but i have the same error.

Comment: @Bellu If this solved your problem please mark it as accepted by ticking the empty V icon to the left.

Comment: @ShadowWizard i forgot it. sorry!

Answer (score 0):

change

If(rsScadenze("testo") <> "") Then

to

If("" & rsScadenze("testo") <> "") Then

why?

in case rsScadenze("testo") comes back as null, adding the "" to it, makes it a ""

it's an easier way to deal with potantial nulls.